# what does {pc}+2 mean in disassembly window?

Tags: disassembly, keil

[image]

Hi.

I'm studying about microprocessor using stm32f103vb board and keil uVision4.

That code is just practice but i don't know what does {pc}+2 mean in red box.

ADR instruction loads address 0x08000338 so that doesn't equal [pc, #2].

what does brace mean??? help me please~

Answer (score 0):

In general, [pc+offset] means instruction pointer, or PC (program counter) relative addressing.

It is used for position independent code in operating systems where PIC support is pervasive. For instance, Linux supports PIC but the norm on Windows is to ditch PIC in favor of PDC.

In your case, it looks like r2 is receiving an address which is 2 units ahead of current instruction (ADR).

Comment: hmm... What I was wondering is not [pc, #offset] but {pc}+2.
I already know what does [pc, #offset] mean.
In practice code, adr instruction loads address of data3(is 32bit data at 0x08000338).
I think that if {pc}+2 is mean like [PC, #offset], result of {pc}+2 is 0x0800031C(=0x0800031A+0x2)........